# Displaying null values after first users login inside android

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I have 3 fragments inside an app and in one of them I display users name from the SQLite database. What happens is when I register a new user and login first time with it, inside the textview where the users name suppose to appear, it displays NULL value, but when I logout and login again with the same user, name appears as it should.

After registering user, all the data is inserted inside a database, I have checked.

Any ideas what can cause this problem? I will add some code on request as I have no idea which part of the code, fragments or java files might cause this..

**EDITED**

I have added some code to help resolve this issue.

Login function inside the main screen (once app launches):

```
private void checkLogin(final String email, final String password) {
    // Tag used to cancel the request
    String tag_string_req = "req_login";

    pDialog.setMessage("Logging in ...");
    showDialog();

    StringRequest strReq = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST,
            AppConfig.URL_LOGIN, new Response.Listener<String>() {

        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {

            Log.d(TAG, "Login Response: " + response.toString());
            hideDialog();


            try {
                JSONObject jObj = new JSONObject(response);
                boolean error = jObj.getBoolean("error");

                // Check for error node in json
                if (!error) {
                    // user successfully logged in
                    // Create login session
                    session.setLogin(true);
                    // Now store the user in SQLite
                    String uid = jObj.getString("uid");

                    JSONObject user = jObj.getJSONObject("user");
                    String name = user.getString("name");
                    String email = user.getString("email");
                    String created_at = user.getString("created_at");

                    // Inserting row in users table
                    db.addUser(name, email, uid, created_at);

                    // Launch main activity
                    Intent intent = new Intent(Main.this,
                            Logged.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                    finish();
                } else {

                    error_msg.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    String msg = jObj.getString("error_msg");
                    error_msg.setText(msg);
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                // JSON error
                e.printStackTrace();
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Json error: " + e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Login Error: " + error.getMessage());
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            hideDialog();
        }
    }) {

        @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
            // Posting parameters to login url
            Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
            params.put("email", email);
            params.put("password", password);

            return params;
        }

    };

    // Adding request to request queue
    AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(strReq, tag_string_req);
}
```

onViewCreated func inside fragment where users name should be diplayed:

```
@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState){

    profileName = (TextView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.profileName);


    // SqLite database handler
    db = new SQLiteHandler(getActivity().getApplicationContext());

    // session manager
    session = new SessionManager(getActivity().getApplicationContext());

    if (!session.isLoggedIn()) {
        logoutUser();
    }

    // Fetching user details from SQLite
    HashMap<String, String> user = db.getUserDetails();

    String name = user.get("name");

    // Displaying the user details on the screen
    profileName.setText(name);

}
```

Register function part:

```
  public void onResponse(String response) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Register Response: " + response.toString());
            hideDialog();

            try {
                JSONObject jObj = new JSONObject(response);
                boolean error = jObj.getBoolean("error");
                if (!error) {

                    // User successfully stored in MySQL
                    // Now store the user in sqlite
                    String uid = jObj.getString("uid");

                    JSONObject user = jObj.getJSONObject("user");
                    String name = user.getString("name");
                    String email = user.getString("email");
                    String created_at = user.getString("created_at");

                    // Inserting row in users table
                    db.addUser(name, email, uid, created_at);

                    // Launch login activity
                    Intent intent = new Intent(
                            Register.this,
                            Main.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                    finish();
                } else {

                    // Error occurred in registration. Get the error
                    // message
                    error_msg.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    String msg = jObj.getString("error_msg");
                    error_msg.setText(msg);


                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Registration Error: " + error.getMessage());
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            hideDialog();
        }
    }) {
```

Comment: are you sure the variable isn't suppose to be null? Do you assign it and then display? Probably would help though with some code to go off of.

Comment: Problem can be at any point - database not returning username, controller/DAO layer not returning correct name back to client or client code not processing correct and hence not displaying .. So, ideally you should put relevant portion from all 3 layers ..

Comment: once the user is registered, his details are added inside the mysql and sqlite databases..All of the data is inserted, but there is nothing null to be diplayed. i will add some code in a second

Comment: @hagrawal but why then it works when user logs in second time?

Comment: That's what we will try to find out ..

Comment: Did you try to debug your `onViewCreated`, hows the database object and value of `db.getUserDetails()` for first and second time ..

Comment: i cant get to work this one, but in monitor for android first time logging in I get `D/SQLiteHandler: Fetching user from Sqlite: {email=null, name=null, created_at=null, uid=null}` and the second time `D/SQLiteHandler: Fetching user from Sqlite: {email=lala, name=lala, created_at=2015-11-12 10:36:08, uid=5644dc18621107.68713025}` I bet i will get the same while debugging

Comment: the problem is with sqlite as It doesnt seem to fetch from it on the first attempt to login..

Comment: Which activity holds the fragment with that TextView? Did you test without your session code to see if by any chance there's the problem? How do you insert the values in the database, synchronously on the main thread or you use some sort of background thread? If after registering the first user, you register another user, you get the same behavior?

Comment: @StuckBetweenTrees can you show how you open "db" in both login and registeration?

Comment: @StuckBetweenTrees In your SQLiteHandler call `Log.d(TAG, "Fetching user from Sqlite: " + user.toString());` in your getUserDetails function to ensure that the data was entered into the db correctly. I had the same issue but found that the data was being entered into the wrong column's. Might help you as well

Comment: @SteveC. no..if I log in the second time it all works fine..its just when the user registers and logs in 1st time this happens..

Comment: I would suggest you consider the Accountmanager instead of sqlite database for storing Account information, accounts will show up in settings of the device. You can easily manage auth tokens, passwords etc. post back and I can show you how.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I managed to sort this problem myself.. The problem was not in java files but in php files sending to java for some reason..

In php function I used:

```
$stmt->bind_result($id, $unique_id, $name, $email, $encrypted_password, $salt, $created_at, $updated_at);
$user = $stmt->fetch();
```

But then changed to

```
$user = $stmt->get_result()->fetch_assoc();
```

And that fixed the problem..